# Rules in .htaccess to block spiders don't appear to be effective, I still see the crawlers in Awstats

Tags: htaccess

I have Put this code in htaccess to prevent search engines accessing my site
However, I still see them listed daily in the AWSTATS file on my sever.

Does this mean they are still searching my site? They haven't infiltrated the site but just logged as an attempt?

```
# Stop the Nasties!!
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^autoemailspider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^baidu [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider* [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bingbot[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Yandex [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Sosospider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^AhrefsBot[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^AITCSRobot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Arachnophilia [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^archive\.org\_bot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BackDoorBot[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BSpider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^CFNetwork[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^CyberPatrol [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DeuSu[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DotBot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailCollector [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FeedlyBot[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Genieo [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Gluten\ Free\ Crawler [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrapeshotCrawler [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MaxPointCrawler [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^meanpathbot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MJ12bot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PagesInventory [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PHP [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Plukkie [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Qwantify [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SemrushBot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SentiBot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SEOkicks\-Robot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SeznamBot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WeSEE\_Bot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^worldwebheritage\.org [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xenu\ Link\ Sleuth [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Yahoo!\ Slurp[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Sogou\web\Spider [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^360Spider [OR]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Yes, this is the code I am using,  copied  from [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess13.shtml). Looking at my RAW log I don't see any forbidden entries Here are 2 examples of today entry Should I delete the OR entries and what do they mean?

```
207.46.13.186 - - [30/Nov/2016:12:05:19 +0000] "GET /comrades/comrades%20football%20team2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 47649 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"

52.213.197.166 - - [03/Dec/2016:14:54:02 +0000] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 1473 "-" "IDG/UK (http://spaziodati.eu/)"
```

Comment: The two log lines you see don't match your rules.   There is no rule at all for `IDG/UK` and your bingbot rule only matches when the user agent *starts* with "Bingbot" (including the capital `B`) because of the `^` in the rule..  The bingbot user agent you posted starts with "Mozilla".

Comment: "copied from here" - Hhhmm, not really "copied", more sort of "loosely based on".

Comment: (w3dk )Loosely based Spot on -  because I had to add/delete engines to fit my circumstances
I have now updated to Stephens post about BingBot
As I said before, I have never had cause to use htaccess to stop spammers so your advice is most welcome
My web site seems to be very popular in the Ukraine and Russia
Last month they devoured 5Gb of bandwidth in one day which didnt please my Hosting Company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> :
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Yahoo!\ Slurp[OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Sogou\web\Spider [OR]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^360Spider [OR]
> RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
> ```

This code is actually "broken" in several places and will never work as intended. In fact, it won't block anything in its current state, which explains your access log.

1. You need to remove the `OR` flag on the last `RewriteCond` directive. This additional `OR` flag would *ordinarily* cause **all traffic to be blocked!**
   (But since you have further errors - see #2 - this does not happen!)
2. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bingbot[OR]`
   You are missing a *space* between the *CondPattern* (`^Bingbot`) and the flags argument (`[OR]`). (It should be `^Bingbot [OR]`.) This won't match "Bingbot". But, crucially, the condition is now an implicit `AND` - so your rule block will never succeed and **no bot will be blocked!** I count at least 7 directives in your code above where the space is missing!
3. As Stephen has already pointed out in comments, the regex used to match these bots do not necessarily seem to be correct. For example, a pattern such as `^Bingbot` matches the exact string "Bingbot" (capital "B") at the *start* of the user-agent (`^` being a start-of-string *anchor*). But the log entry you've shown contains "bingbot" (all lowercase) in the *middle* of the user-agent string. This will not match. You probably need a condition like the following, without a `^` prefix and with the `NC` flag for a case-insensitive match:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bingbot [NC,OR]
   ```

   You'll need to check the other regex, whether they match the User-Agent you are trying to target. Are you matching at the start of the UA (`^`)? Should it be case-insensitive (`NC`)?
4. Minor point... Given the following two directives, the first one is superfluous. However, the second one looks like an error.

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Baiduspider* [OR]
   ```

> However, I still see them listed daily in the AWSTATS file on my sever.

Yes, even if you block the bots (once your code is working), they will still "hit" your server and be logged in the server's access log from which AWStats builds its reports.

However, check your raw access log and you should see a 403 (Forbidden) in the response status for these requests (this is probably reported in AWStats as well). If not, then something is wrong.

The `RewriteRule` can also be simplified:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

The `L` flag is implied when you use the `F` flag.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more explanation regarding the `^` (caret/hat) at the start of the _CondPattern_ (which is a _regular expression_ or _regex_ for short). No, this is not always required (see #3 above). You need to use the appropriate regex for the user-agent string you are trying to match.